# "Inconvertible types" when using an implementation of an interface

Tags: java, interface

I'm encountering an unexpected error ("inconvertible types") when trying to cast an implementation of an interface to the interface.

I'm given the following interface

```
public interface IAbc {...}
```

and the following method in another class

```
public class SomeClass {
    public doSomething(Iterable<IAbc> abcs) {...}
}
```

I've written the following class

```
public class MyAbc implements IAbc {...}
```

I've got a method elsewhere like this

```
public class MyClass {
    public Iterable<MyAbc> getMyAbcs() {...}
}
```

I expected I could link these up nicely as follows:

```
public void doSomethingWithThings(SomeClass sc, MyClass mc) {
    sc.doSomething(mc.getMyAbcs());
}
```

but NetBeans is giving me the following error:

> error: inconvertible types
>   `sc.doSomething(mc.getMyAbcs());`
>   required: Iterable
>   found: Iterable

I tried casting, but `Iterable<IAbc> abc = (Iterable<IAbc>)mc.getMyAbcs();` causes the same error.

How can I pass an Iterable of implementation of an interface to a method expecting an Iterable of the interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Iterable<MyAbc>` is **not** a `Iterable<IAbc>`, even though `MyAbc` is a `IAbc`.

Try a wildcard like so:

```
public doSomething(Iterable<? extends IAbc> abcs) {...}
```

This is the opposite of arrays, with arrays: `MyAbc[]` is a `Iabc[]`

Here's a good tutorial for more http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option (I can't change `SomeClass` or `IAbc`).

Comment: @Jim then you need to manually transform it to `Iterable<IAbc>` before calling the function, and pass the `Iterable<IAbc>` to it. Or just strictly use `Iterable<IAbc>` by having the method in your class return `Iterable<IAbc>`

Comment: @Jim you should also inform the author of the api to use properly bounded wildcard to make it work like expected :P